# Simulating contenteditable in SVG without foreignobject

Tags: html, svg, contenteditable

I have written a web-application where users can create svg elements with text. I want to simulate contenteditable elements inside the svg elements, so that users can dynamically edit the content of the svg elements. That is, when a user clicks on one of these elements, a cursor should appear so that the text can be edited. I do not want to use foreignobject to achieve this, since this is not supported by IE. I couldn't find anything useful about this online, so is there any way to do this?

EDIT: To clarify, here is an example:

```
<svg>
    <rect width="192" height="192" style="stroke-width: 3; fill:red"></rect>
    <text x="30" y="20">A sample text</text><!-- when the user clicks on this, it should be editable-->
</svg>
```

Comment: Not sure why Erik isn't a credible or official source. He is is one of the editors of the SVG specification.

Answer (score 17):

Here's an example:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <svg>
        <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="5" fill="green" />
        <text y="2em">Hello world</text>
    </svg>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZEAwB/

Works in Opera 18, Chrome 33, Firefox (Nightly) 28 and IE9. Probably works in earlier versions of Opera, Chrome and Firefox too, not quite sure how far back though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This does not seem to work for nested SVG though, e.g. when I want to edit content in a circle which is itself contained in another svg-element, for example a g-element. The cursor is also placed badly on chrome 31, but I should be able to work around that.

Comment: update: doesn't work in latest chrome (49.0.2623.110)

Comment: @Erik Dalhström, Is there a good reason why contenteditable is on the outer <div> element instead of the actual target element <text>?

Comment: @ATL_DEV I was wondering the same - it looks like it is because it's not part of the SVG specification and thus it won't work - there is a proposal for adding it though, copying the HTML semantics: https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/332

Comment: Don't work in Chrome (114.0.5735.199) in July 2023.

Answer (score 2):

@Erik Dalhström's solution doesn't seem to address the question: He wants to be able to edit text content atop ("inside") an SVG object, as the example showed. On Firefox, Erik's code indeed makes the text editable, but beneath the 10 x 10 circle, and not inside the SVG space.

I found a workaround at https://github.com/artursapek/mondrian/issues/12 :

when the user clicks on an SVG `<text>` element,
set the `contenteditable`attribute on the nearest ancestor in HTML namespace to `true`
(e.g. `document.body.contentEditable = true;`),
then make the SVG `<text>` element selectable
(e.g. `svgTextElement.style.webkitUserSelect = 'text';`).

When the user finishes editing the text (e.g. by clicking on canvas)
set the `contentEditable` attribute on the ancestor back to `false`.

I haven't tried this, hope someone reports back if this works.
We shouldn't have to wait for CSS 2.0 to get this very obviously needed functionality.

Comment: Why the copy paste is not working in your example? https://github.com/artursapek/mondrian/issues/12