# contentedible attribute on svg text not working

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am using d3 on my application. And this svg has multiple text elements.

I want to be able to edit them with the contentedible attribute.

Here is the code I use:

```html
<svg class='wordcloud-svg' height="572" width="1440" text-anchor="middle" viewbox="0 0 50 50"></svg>
```

```js
const svg = d3.select('.wordcloud-svg')          
svg.append('text')
    .text("test")
    .style('font-size', "13")
    .attr('class', "keyword")
    .style('fill', '#E24C14')
    .style('font-family', "'ABeeZee', sans-serif")
    .style('margin', "3px")
    .attr('contenteditable', "true")
})
```

All the other styles/attributes all work perfectly, except the contenteditable.

I am not sure why, it works on regular HTML text elements (e.g. h1)

I have tried to use "editable" too, but that yielded no results.

Can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: The contenteditable attribute is not supported on a SVG text element. A possible workaround is to wrap the SVG inside an editable div. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20429580/simulating-contenteditable-in-svg-without-foreignobject to see if it fits your use case.

Comment: If you need to change the text inside an svg element you may try to put it inside a <foreignObject> paragraph and make the <p> contenteditable. If you put the SVG inside an editable div the users will be able to delete the whole svg element.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("IDmySVG").setAttribute("contenteditable", "true" );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: As commented: `contenteditable` can be applied to parent HTML elements but not to svg elements directly.